# Redirecting subdomain of add-on domain on hostmonster.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, hostmonster

I am having issues with restricting access to *only* the add-on domain. I do not wish to be able to access the files through the primary domain.

I have my primary domain hosted with hostmonster.com which is *mydomain.co.uk*. I have three 'addon' domains:

> addondomain1.com
>
> addondomain2.com
>
> addondomain3.com

They could be accessed by visiting

> addondomain1.mydomain.co.uk OR mydomain.co.uk/domains/addondomain1
>
> addondomain2.mydomain.co.uk OR mydomain.co.uk/domains/addondomain2
>
> addondomain3.mydomain.co.uk OR mydomain.co.uk/domains/addondomain3

I have added a subdomain 'dev' for *addondomain1* which can be accessed by visiting

> mydomain.co.uk/domains/addondomain1/dev OR dev.addondomain1.mydomain.co.uk

If anyone can give me some pointers as to what my *.htaccess* should look like that would be great. I assume I may have to have two *.htaccess* files. One in the 'addondomain1' directory and one in the 'dev' directory within that.

What I have so far: *.htaccess*

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?addondomain1.$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.addondomain1.mydomain.co.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dev.addondomain1.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?dev/(.*)$ http://dev.addondomain1.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addondomain1.mydomain.co.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.addondomain1.mydomain.co.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.addondomain1.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://addondomain1.com/ [R=301,L]

    Redirect 301 /domains/addondomain1 http://addondomain1.com
```

I currently get an error in the browser stating that it cannot load the page because too many redirects are occurring. It appears to be stuck in a loop.

The result that I would like is to be able to access the files solely through:

dev.addondomain1.com

Comment: If you setup your `VirtualHost` correct and set `DocumentRoot` of `dev.addondomain1.com` to `mydomain.co.uk/domains/addondomain1/dev` then you don't need any rewrite rule.

Comment: That is setup correctly, however, as my question states you can still access those files through the primary domain. I do not want this.

Comment: So `dev.addondomain1.com` is working fine but you just want to block access to `dev.addondomain1.com` files from parent domains?

Comment: Yes :) and also from the domain itself as you can access those files through addondomain1.com/dev too

Answer (score 1):

On inside `mydomain.co.uk/domains/addondomain1/dev/.htaccess` insert this rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.addondomain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```